# Is there any way to abort db flush operation in doctrine preFlush() event listener?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I do `$entityManager->flush()` after which listener handler `preFlush()` gets executed.

What I want to achieve is: If a condition fails in preFlush() function, is there any way to not do the db flush Or in other words abort the flush operation?

Comment: I am not really sure but I think that if you throw some kind of exception the flush operation will be halted and rolled back

Comment: @CarlosGranados - I think that might work.  But for now have used another approach to my problem.  Will come to this sometime later and update the status after trying your hint.  Thanks.

Comment: @jitendra, did you have success with this?